# Why UnboundLocalError occurs when inner function assign value to local variables

Tags: python

I'm writing an inner function in an outer function, then something that's wired happened, that is when assigning a value to a local variable in the inner function, a UnBoundLocalError occurred. Conversely, if I just print out the local variable in the inner function, it works pretty well. Let me show you the simplified code. I know this is something that's relevant to LEGB rules in Python, but I still couldn't find out why it happened. Appreciate a lot if someone could give me some insights. Let me show you the simplified code.

```py
def outer1():
    number = 10
    def inner():
        print(number)
    inner()

def outer2():
    number = 20
    def inner():
        if number >= 20:
            number += 1
    inner()
```

`outer1()` function works well, but `outer2()` function throw out a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment`.

I know using the `nonlocal` keyword could solve the problem. but there is still something confused me. Why `if` statement in the `outer2()` function didn't look up variable `number` in the outer function like what `outer1()` function did. Anyone could give me some explanations about that?

Comment: You have assigned to `number` within `inner()` in the second case. That makes it a local variable to `inner()`. But you have not assigned it any value within `inner()` before trying to use it. It does not inherit the value of `number` from `outer()` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `nonlocal` statement in such cases:

```
def outer2():
    number = 20
    def inner():
        nonlocal number
        if number >= 20:
            number += 1
    inner()
```

To get understand why, lets look at bytecode:

```
import dis


def outer2():
    number = 20
    def inner():
        if number >= 20:
            number
    inner()



def outer3():
    number = 20
    def inner():
        if number >= 20:
            number = number + 1
    inner()


def outer4():
    number = 20
    def inner():
        nonlocal number
        if number >= 20:
            number = number + 1
    inner()

>>> dis.dis(outer2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (20)
              3 STORE_DEREF              0 (number)

  3           6 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (number)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object inner at 0x7ff003b56b70, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
             15 LOAD_CONST               3 ('outer2.<locals>.inner')
             18 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             21 STORE_FAST               0 (inner)

  6          24 LOAD_FAST                0 (inner)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             30 POP_TOP
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE


>>> dis.dis(outer3)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (20)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (number)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object inner at 0x7ff003b56ae0, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 ('outer3.<locals>.inner')
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 STORE_FAST               1 (inner)

  6          18 LOAD_FAST                1 (inner)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             24 POP_TOP
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE


>>> dis.dis(outer4)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (20)
              3 STORE_DEREF              0 (number)

  3           6 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (number)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object inner at 0x7ff003af7e40, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
             15 LOAD_CONST               3 ('outer4.<locals>.inner')
             18 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             21 STORE_FAST               0 (inner)

  7          24 LOAD_FAST                0 (inner)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             30 POP_TOP
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

From these examples one can see, that trying to assign to a variable (that wasn't declared as nonlocal) 
yields to `MAKE_FUNCTION` opcode. But only closures allow to get access variables out of the current scope. 
You can also read more about closures [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-closures/).

Note: This was tested in Python 3.5; Also read about [changes](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/3.6.html) regrading `MAKE_FUNCTION` and `MAKE_CLOSURE` opcodes in python 3.6

Comment: I know using the nonlocal keyword could solve the problem. but there is still something confused me. Why if statement in the outer2() function didn't look up variable `number` in the outer function like what outer1() function did. Could you give me some explanations about that?

Comment: Thanks very much. You make me fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def outer2():
  number = 20
  def inner():
     nonlocal number # this is the additional change required
     if number >= 20:
         number += 1
  inner()
```

In python functions it is possible to access 'global' variables inside functions and even their methods, but not assign values to them, because then the function looks for its local copy of the variable. 
The error is because the function looks for the local variable 'number' in its symbol table entry and doesn't find it.

This could usually be handled by using the global keyword to specify that the variable you are editing has a global scope, but since the function is defined in another function you will need to use the 'nonlocal' keyword, which is another way of saying that the variable you want to modify is not local to that function, but to the function in which it is defined in, which is outer2 in this case.